How to prove that forall n m, n <= m -> m <= n -> n = m
Theorem le_trans: forall n m o, n <= m -> m <= o -> n <= o.
Proof.
 intros n m o Lnm Lmo.
 generalize dependent Lnm.  
 generalize dependent n.
 induction Lmo.
 - intros. apply Lnm.
 - intros. apply le_S. apply IHLmo. apply Lnm.
Qed.

how to prove:
Theorem le_antisym: forall n m, n <= m -> m <= n -> n = m.

I don't know if there is a relationship between the two propositions, if I need to use the first proposition to aid in proving the second, and if so, how to prove it, and if not, how to prove it.

These questions highly depend on how <= is defined. Using the inductive characterization from the StdLib, one could for example proceed as:
Fact le_trans n m p : n <= m -> m <= p -> n <= p.
Proof. 
  induction 2.
  + trivial.
  + now constructor.
Qed.

Fact le_n_Sn n : n <= S n.
Proof. do 2 constructor. Qed. 

Fact le_S_inv n m :
      n <= m
   -> match n, m with 
      | 0, _     => True
      | S _, 0   => False
      | S n, S m => n <= m
      end.
Proof.
  induction 1 as [ | m H _ ]; destruct n; auto.
  apply le_trans with (2 := H), le_n_Sn.
Qed.

Fact le_anti n m : le n m -> le m n -> n = m.
Proof.
  induction n in m |- *; destruct m;
    intros ?%le_S_inv ?%le_S_inv; tauto || auto.
Qed.

The inversion lemma le_S_inv is a critical tool here. It consists in studying the interaction between an inductive predicate and a pattern matching on the shape of parameters.

One could also use the mathcomp library to prove such a lemma using rewriting (of course, proving the key eqn_leq lemma would still need some induction):
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Theorem le_antisym: forall n m, n <= m -> m <= n -> n = m.
Proof. by move=> n m nm mn; apply/eqP; rewrite eqn_leq nm mn. Qed.


Completely opaque, especially if not even stepping through is possible...

The definition of eqn_leq may help: Lemma eqn_leq m n : (m == n) = (m ≤ n ≤ m).

Also, note that m <= n <= m is a notation for the boolean conjunction (m <= n) && (n <= m).
